# Alternative for Multiple copy activity executing and pushing data into multiple tables

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've have an ADFV2 pipeline which has sequential activities as
**Wait** (3secs) >>  **StoredProcedure** which truncates and drops FK from 41 tables >> 41 **Copy** activities which takes data from Azure blob container and then dumps them into 41 tables on SQL Server(on Azure), these 41 copy activities are parallely triggered.

This setup is working fine but i want to remove clutter from my pipeline. So to achieve it i tired **Foreach** with **Lookup** it didn't work out, i tried **Until**, it also doesn't suites my requirements.

Is there a way to achieve my setup with a different approach or the best way to achieve the goal is current setup only?

[image: Glimpse of Pipeline]

Comment: The best way for me is a lookup with a foreach after it. What didnt work when you tried?

Comment: With lookup i was fetching the table name which needs to be dumped to Sql Server but the activity i want to perform in ForEach activity is different in all 41 Copy activity. All 41 copy activity uses different source and sink dataset.

Comment: You can also use parameters in the dataset definition!! Use "@item().TableName" in the table field on you dataset definition

Comment: You could do things more dynamically, see [here](https://sqlofthenorth.blog/2018/06/20/loading-multiple-tables-with-azure-data-factory/) for an example.